# How to show html <input> marks to Views Custom text - field?

Tags: views, entities, input-formats, theming

I need to put < input    > - html tag to my Views Custom text field, but it wont show up? Somehow these codes will be disabled? What I need to do?

I tried to find solutions from web, but I didnt find anything for this. But I really need to put these html to Views custom text - field.

Text format settings is fine, but no help.

This works when I put < input > tag to Views "Header" and "Footer" section with "Custom text" field, but  why not in section "fields"?

I hope there is a simple solution for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar problems trying to show a  tag. The only way I've been able to get around it is to install the Views PHP module - https://drupal.org/project/views_php - and add the HTML through that

Hope this helps you!

Comment: aside from custom tpl file, this is the only solution i see as well. Be careful though, because this module is a huge security risk. These custom text fields write to the database directly and will allow hackers to inject PHP into your site via the database. So use with caution